# How to solve the arrow in geom_segment can‘t display under plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I draw a picture using ggplot2. I use arrow option in geom_segment because of directed picture. But when I display my pic under plotly using ggplotly, the Arrow disappear. How can I display the arrow ?
You can run the following code to debug.

```
positiox_positiony <- data.frame(x_position=1:2,y_position=3:4)
node_edge_xy <- data.frame(x=1,y=3,xend=2,yend=4)
p <- ggplot(positiox_positiony,aes(x=x_position,y=y_position))+
  geom_point(color="red",size=10,alpha=0.8)+
  geom_segment(data=node_edge_xy,aes(x = x,y = y,xend = xend,yend = yend),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.25,"cm"),ends="last",type="closed"))
p

ggplotly(p)
```

Answer (score 5):

An inelegant solution: add the arrow using `plotly` annotations.

```
g <- ggplotly(p) %>%
      layout(annotations=list(
         list(
           x=positiox_positiony$x_position[2],
           y=positiox_positiony$y_position[2],
           showarrow=TRUE,
           xref = "x",
           yref = "y",
           arrowhead = 2,
           arrowsize = 1.5,
           ax=-20,
           ay=20
         )
))
g
```

[image]